# Matlab Zooming Using Pixel Replication

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I was trying to zoom an image using pixel replication method. The code below has a "Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen;". I don't know if this is the problem with the output. The output is totally displaying something else. Here is a link to the output... https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixl80jwutra8e1a/Q.PNG

```
Img = handles.Image;
temp = double(imread(Img));
b=temp;
[m,n,colormap]=size(b);

%If RGB Image is given at Input 
if colormap==3
x=b(:,:,1);
y=b(:,:,2);
z=b(:,:,3);
end

k=1; %Counter for Row and
l=1; %Column replication
f=2; %Replica factor

for i=1:m %Loop for reading row and
    for t=1:f %Row replication

        for j=1:n %Loop for reading column and
            for t=1:f %Column replication

                if colormap==3 %If Image is RGB
                c1(k,l)= x(i,j);
                c2(k,l)= y(i,j);
                c3(k,l)= z(i,j);
                else %If Image is grayscale
                c(k,l)=b(i,j);
                end
                l=l+1;
            end
        end
        l=1;
        k=k+1;

    end
end

if colormap==3 %If Image is RGB
    c(:,:,1)=c1;
    c(:,:,2)=c2;
    c(:,:,3)=c3;
end
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(c);
```

What exactly is the problem, is there any way out?

Comment: Just a quick look but at first sight it seems you are doing `l=1;` in the wrong place - shouldn't it be after the `for t` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You get a warning because `imshow` automatically scale the images to fit the screen if they are two big. And it tells you it did.

If you want to force the output to be scaled 1:1, you can use:

```
imshow(c, 'InitialMagnification', 100);
```